# How to open pom.xml project using IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to learn about annotation processing by looking at this [sample](https://github.com/sockeqwe/annotationprocessing101).

I've cloned it to my local machine and used IDEA to open it.

However IDEA tells me:

> Project SDK not set up.

After setting up Java SDK, the project is not opening correctly. So how can I open this project?

The project structure :

```
 annotationprocessing10
     |
     |------factory
              |-----annotation
                        |------pom.xml
              |-----processor
                        |------pom.xml
              |-----pom.xml
    |-------factory-sample
```

I tried opening `annotationprocessing10` (root) directly and also tried `factory` directly but neither worked. Here is a screenshot of the directory structure:
[image: project directory structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given repo is not a maven module (no POM.xml in the base directory), the maven modules are the projects inside.

Make sure you import the modules inside the root directory in IDEA to identify it as a maven project.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can you put that in here?

Comment: No errors but it seems strange. I upload my screenshot.

Comment: It seems correct to me, this is how IntelliJ renders projects - If you're used to Eclipse, the look and feel is vastly different in IntelliJ

Comment: How do you open this repo? Can you list your step?